# Email Sender name is not correct in all emails in Magento 2.3

Tags: email, magento2.3.0, send-mail

After upgrading in Magento 2.3.1, Email sender name is not showing correct as configured in admin.

If Email info@example.com is configured in admin then sender name is showing "info".

How can I fix the issue? can anyone suggest.

Comment: Recheck your settings also check that you have not assigned on store level aswell as default level

Comment: How did you fix this, I am also facing same issue

Comment: @SudheerSingamsetti,  I have worked   "vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php"

Comment: update header information in the function:  "public function mailHandler($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $parameters)"

Comment: the same issue in Magento 2.3.3 have u any solution? @VinodKumar